# How to stop program execution in worksheet?

Tags: scala, scala-ide

How can program execution be stopped in the Scala worksheet ?

If code is executing and does not return (an infinite loop) it does not seem possible to stop the program execution without re-starting Eclipse ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-worksheet/wiki/Getting-Started :

> If the program takes too long to execute, the editor adds a spinning
>   bar after 2 seconds. You can interrupt the evaluation at any point by
>   typing any character or Esc.