# How do I stop a non-terminating Scala worksheet in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, worksheet

using Idea 12.5 and Scala 2.10 on OS X

How do I stop a non terminating call in a Scala worksheet? Say I evaluate the following worksheet via the green 'play' button on the worksheet, or *alt-cmd-W*:

def loop():Unit = { println("looping") ; loop() }
  loop()

Unlike (and why, btw, is this different?) when I run it via a runtime configuration (Run > Run...) where the Run tool window pops up (View > Tool Windows > Run) with its option to stop the execution (*cmd+F2*), I seem to have no way of stopping the worksheet.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836329/how-to-stop-program-execution-in-worksheet) (I know it is for Eclipse, but linking could be usefull for people who will stumble this question later)

Comment: What does it mean - "runtime configuration ^R where the Run tool window pops up"? I've just tried run worksheet as scala file (Ctrl+Shift+F10) and evaluate (Ctrl+Alt+W) and in both cases Ctrl+F2 works fine.

Comment: hm. certainly not working for me. It completely stalls IDEA and I end up force quitting IDEA.